# String? can't be assigned to type string in flutter while converting url to ID for youtube API

Tags: dart

```
var url = document['url'];
YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
                    initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url

),
```

Answer (score 2):

this is null-safety common mistake
YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url) will return String?
you have to check if it == null  then alert the user or show snack bar or some thing
else use it like this YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url)! to return String without the ? null-able operator